# Recovering data saved in .npz files

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Brief background: I'm an applied mathematics student who finally needs to learn to code; I started learning Python several weeks ago in order to join in a research project running climatological data analyses. I have literally been coding (besides maple and mathematica stuff) for 4 weeks, so go easy on me; I'll do my best to provide only signal and no noise (like this paragraph).

I have a script which runs analysis, and I've finally gotten it to run. Creates a number of NumPy arrays (which are those referenced in the directory saved below) and then saves it to an .npz file. (I'm tortuously running this on Windows 10:/)

```
    np.savez('pr_zonaltimemean.npz', \
         **{'pr_aqct':pr_aqct, 'pr_aq4x':pr_aq4x, 'pr_ldct':pr_ldct, \
            'pr_ld4x':pr_ld4x, 'pr_ldor':pr_ldor, 'lat':lat} )
```

Something is going wrong at this stage though: the .npz file, when opened (either by just opening the file through Jupyter or Notepad ++ yields nothing meaningful.

1) If I click open the file in the Jupyter terminal I get a message saying that the file isn't UTF-8 encoded; I then converted the file to UTF-8 in Notepad ++, (in which the file displayed as random characters and black blocks). Jupyter will open the converted file, but again as mush, though the variable names do appear in the mush.

2) When I use `numpy.load()` on the unconverted file I get: `numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile at 0x8eb33c8`.
When I use it on the converted file I get a string of errors:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call    last)
        <ipython-input-4-9ad538351ff5> in <module>()
    ----> 1 np.load('1pr_globaltimemean.npz')

    C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.pyc in      load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
        397             own_fid = False
        398             return NpzFile(fid, own_fid=tmp,       allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
     -->399                            pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
        400         elif magic == format.MAGIC_PREFIX:
        401             # .npy file

    C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.pyc in    __init__(self, fid, own_fid, allow_pickle, pickle_kwargs)
        160         # Import is postponed to here since zipfile depends on  gzip, an
        161         # optional component of the so-called standard library.
    --> 162         _zip = zipfile_factory(fid)
        163         self._files = _zip.namelist()
        164         self.files = []

    C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.pyc in      zipfile_factory(*args, **kwargs)
         90     import zipfile
         91     kwargs['allowZip64'] = True 
    ---> 92     return zipfile.ZipFile(*args, **kwargs)
         93 
         94 

    C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\lib\zipfile.pyc in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64)
        768         try:
        769             if key == 'r':
    --> 770                 self._RealGetContents()
        771             elif key == 'w':
        772                 # set the modified flag so central directory  gets written

    C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda2\lib\zipfile.pyc in _RealGetContents(self)
        827         # self.start_dir:  Position of start of central directory
        828         self.start_dir = offset_cd + concat
    --> 829         fp.seek(self.start_dir, 0)
        830         data = fp.read(size_cd)
        831         fp = cStringIO.StringIO(data)

    IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Sorry if the above isn't formatted correctly.

I tried running the analysis (to create the above directories) without saving to the .npz file, and this yields legitimate arrays. I tried creating only one of the arrays and saving it into a .npy file (`numpy.save`). This I could open easily, but I don't know if I can save all of the arrays and access them via a directory as the code is intended to do. I didn't write this code (nor could I have, I'm just able to parse it). So the data is being created correctly in numpy arrays but something is going wrong in the saving process and I have no idea how or why.

If someone can figure out why the .npz files are either a) Not saving the arrays correctly or b) not opening correctly on my computer that would be awesome. If this isn't possible, an alternative suggestion would be fine.

Comment: The file is not a text file; you can not view it in a meaningful way in Notepad or any other text editor.  The data is stored in a compressed binary format.  Do not attempt to convert it to UTF-8--it will just mangle the binary data and result in garbage.  Try loading the *unconverted* file using `numpy.load()`.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried; sorry for not noting so above. It yields this:                  `numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile at 0x8eb33c8`

Comment: That's fine.  If you use `result = numpy.load('pr_zonaltimemean.npz')`, then `result` is an instance of `NpzFile`, which is a dictionary-like object that holds the arrays that were stored in the file.  Then, for example, you can get the `pr_aqct` array using `result['pr_aqct']`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much!